# Do we have to consider Browser Zoom when building a WebSite.?

Tags: css, layout, web

I am building a site for my friend, He specified a bug for me. He said,"When I Zoom in/out the browser,  the Website layout “breaks apart” but it is working fine in 100% Browser Zoom."

Please let me know the Standard for web development for Browser Zooming

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CSS there is something called "em". Different from pixels, they adjust themselves to screen settings. With most CSS elements, zooms should not be  a problem, but if you are really having trouble, I would recommend using em as units

Answer (score 1):

usually I don't consider zooming but if you want a good website that shows ok with different screen resolutions like in mobile browsers or tablet you'd better use responsive style sheets.
you do not need to write it by your own. you can use style sheets like twitter bootstrap which already supports responsive web pages 
you can download it from here [enter link description here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)

Answer (score 0):

The webpage should be responsive enough like to work for "smaller screens" that is more or less how it will work for your CSS when they zoom in.

Make sure you have min-width or min-height set to your body or general container so, when it gets to this minimums it just stais as it looks.

For example, for the SO webpage, you have the div with id "content" inside the general div.container that has a width of 980px, so if you zoom in a lot it just shows the bottom scrollbar.